# mysql select all table names except

Tags: sql, mysql

Alright, I know you can do the following to get all column names.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM person;
```

However, it does not allow where statements.

Is there any way to get the full list and just say not this one?

So I am basically looking for something like this:

```
select (show columns from person where Field <> 'id') from person
```

Comment: The system I am on is using mysql 4 not 5.

Comment: That would be useful to know :) It is like using SQL Server 7.0, where we need to dig out super ninja powers for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USe `SHOW [FULL] COLUMNS {FROM | IN} tbl_name [{FROM | IN} db_name] [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]`
Example:

SHOW CHARACTER SET WHERE `Default collation` LIKE '%japanese%';

[More about show here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/extended-show.html)

Try something like `SHOW COLUMNS FROM person WHERE column != 'value';`

Comment: Show columns ... with any where does not work; at least for me.

Comment: That WHERE clause should be `WHERE field != 'value'`. Check the output of `SHOW COLUMNS` to see the field names.

Comment: This will work in mysql5 just not mysql4 but is the best choice. If mysql4 just going to be stuck with listing all fields.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use proper a SQL query against information_schema

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'test'    # your db name
and table_name = 'person '
and column_name != 'id'
```

For MySQL **4**, you can use LIKE directly instead of WHERE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-columns.html

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM 'Person' LIKE '%x%'
```

However unfortunately, that does not support a **NOT** clause.

If I may suggest

- If you need this information from
  MySQL console/phpAdmin/equivalent,
  just eyeball it..
- If you need this
  from a front-end program like php, do
  it from that environment.

Comment: I am not trying to sound condescending but information_schema does not exist in the mysql4 db I am having to use.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) says that WHERE clause is allowed. Read the docs.

Comment: We are using mysql4 not 5. And maybe it the setup we have but I am not able to use where in a show column command otherwise I would not had to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a true `SHOW COLUMNS WHERE` in MySQL 4. The docs show only an optional `LIKE` parameter for that version: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-columns.html

However, you can use the metadatabase information_schema.

```
USE information_schema;
SELECT * FROM `COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = 'person' AND `COLUMN_NAME` != 'value';
```